# Simple Calculation Iterating through Every Row - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How do I create a new dataframe `bigdf` with a calculated column that iterates through every row from another dataframe `df`? I receive empty rows in the new dataframe `bigdf`.

```
# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
  
# DataFrame
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])
```

Iterate through every row to calculate each rows age minus the average

```
bigdf = pd.DataFrame()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    bigdf['score'] = row['Age']-np.average(df['Age'])

print(bigdf)

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [score]
Index: []
```

Comment: Why don't you just do `bigdf['score'] = bigdf['Age']-np.average(df['Age'])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation will be very slow. Note that you compute the mean of `df['Age']` in every iteration of your for loop - this has quadratic runtime. You should never iterate over rows of a dataframe unless there is really no other option.

In this case, you are simply trying to compute the signed difference between each row's age and the average age, which can be done with a single vectorized operation:

```
bigdf['score'] = df['Age'] - df['Age'].mean()
```